Extension for adding a Custom Button the Team Explorer of Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to create an extension that will add a custom button to the Visual Studio 2022 Team Explorer window. On clicking the button I want to do some operations in the Version Control.

I built that application using Visual Studio 2019 by extending the "ITeamExplorerNavigationItem" of the "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls". But in VS2022 it is not working.
I can see some changes in the way extension creation is created in VS 2022. Can you please let me know how I can extend the Team Explorer window of Visual Studio in VS 2022?

The Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll of VS2022 is typically placed in the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022.

Your question is way too broad to be answered in an useful way. Do you have a specific issue you are encountering?
Between VS 2019 and 2022 lots of things changed regarding extension authoring

Update a Visual Studio extension for Visual Studio 2022
Breaking API changes in Visual Studio 2022

You can also try looking at working extensions which have functionality similar to what you are describing. Maybe that's enough to get you started. e.g. SonarLint for Visual Studio 2022 in SonarQubeNavigationItem.cs is adding a simple button which then just opens a page which just displays some text

Hi,
Earlier I was using the "ITeamExplorerNavigationItem" of VS2019 placed in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll. But now I am not finding similar dll for VS2022. So basically I wanted to add a button to the team explorer window of VS2022.


the "ITeamExplorerNavigationItem" of VS2019 placed in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\xxx But now I am not finding similar dll for VS2022.

If you want to find the  location of "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll" for VS2022, you can find in the following folder.
Default path:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer

If you have customized the installation location for VS2022, you can find the location of VS2022 via VS Installer.(VS Installer->Modify->Installation Locations)

For more information, please read: Select the installation locations in Visual Studio
